# Checking if a file exists on your computer

Tags: c#, xml

Basically i have a list of folder paths on XML File.  I created a dataGrid View which reads this XML file and displays the list of folders in the XML into the data Grid View.  Now I need to create a way  where the user chooses a folder path from one of the list I have and the program will check if this folder exists on the computer being used.Is there a way to create this program?

Comment: did you google it? `Directory.Exists()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: DLehs answer or [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes I know about the File.Exists infact it is the one I have tried.  But the problem is i do not know how to connect that to a windows form program.  I wish that when the folder path is put on a text Box and a button next to it is chosen it searches for the file.  Do you know how to code that ? @DLeh

Comment: see the comment above  @DavidBrabant

Comment: See the comment where i explain to Dleh @CarstenKönig

Comment: @Jack ... have you tried using an event-handler for the `Click` event of said button? ... Please don't get me wrong but that seems to be WinForms 101 and this will be a long thread if we have to give you the very basics - maybe you should look for a beginners tutorial or book?

Comment: @CarstenKönig yes i used an event-handler.  For now i have tried that when the button is pressed if the file exists it shows me a message. This is the coding :     private void button3_Click(object sender,                        EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists("test 2.text"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("works");

            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Button with event handler for the click event and assuming that your input textbox is named textBoxForPath this should work:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = this.textBoxForPath.Text;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used it but it didn't work I programmed it that it shows a message box saying this folder is in your computer.  But when I give the folder path in the text box and press the button no messagebox shows